# Is there a non-memory-intensive way of importing data from MariaDB into Python?

Tags: python, sql, linux, memory, mariadb

**Question**

Is there a non-memory-intensive way for extracting large datasets from a MariaDB database and importing them directly into Python (via the python-mariadb connector)?

**Edit: Solution**

Following @Georg Richter's [solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77960704), we can do:

```
connection = mariadb.connect(user='<username>', host='localhost', database='my_database')
cursor = connection.cursor(buffered=False)
query = 'SELECT column_1,column_2 FROM my_table'
cursor.execute(query)
df = pd.DataFrame({col:[] for col in range(number_of_columns_you_extract)})
size = 2**23
while rows := cursor.fetchmany(size):
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(rows)], copy=False)
```

For some reason, this casts my int values as float. But memory usage never exceeds 10GB.

**Context**

I have a large database in MariaDB on Linux. I often have to import parts of it into Python for further computations. MariaDB is quite economical in terms of its memory usage, but Python is not. Although there are less memory-intensive ways to hold the data in Python (e.g., as a Pandas DataFrame with appropriate dtypes for all columns), the usual workflow involves copying data several times and in some stages the memory requirements are enormous.

**Simple Example**

```
import pandas as pd
import mariadb
import gc

connection = mariadb.connect(user='<username>', host='localhost', database='my_database')
cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=False)
query = 'SELECT column_1,column_2 FROM my_table'
cursor.execute(query)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
del cursor
gc.collect()
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
del rows
gc.collect()
```

The example extracts 500 million rows and two columns, all values are integers.

After `cursor.execute(query)`, the memory usage is about 35GB. After `rows = cursor.fetchall()`, it rises to about 90GB. After converting the data to a pandas DataFrame and removing the other objects, the memory requirements fall to about 8GB. I monitored the memory usage using top.

I am unsure how the data is saved in the cursor object. I `rows`, it is a list of tuples. (And if you do `cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=True)` to preserve the column names, it is instead a list of dicts, each with the column names as strings. Needless to say, in that case, the memory requirements rise far beyond the 90GB reported above.)

**Ideas for solutions**

- Cutting out the two intermediate stages of saving the data (after `cursor.execute()` and after `cursor.fetchall()`) and save directly into a pandas DataFrame. Python-mariadb does not seem to offer this. It does not strike me as something that would be easy to implement.
- Importing the data in chunks. In this case, I am worried about (1) possible dtype inconsistencies, (2) memory requirements when concatenating the dataframes into one in the end, (3) possible inconsistencies this might introduce in case of more complex MariaDB queries (especially with ad hoc implementations of splitting the query result into chunks), and (4) the computation time, if in the worst possible case the query may have to be run ay many times as there ara chunks.
- Saving the query results to the hard drive and reading it back into pandas. This would basically mean working around everything the python-mariadb connector has implemented and replacing it with manual hacks. In addition, this may lead to problems with write permissions to the hard drive. (I have `ProtectHome=true` in the MariaDB config, which will prevent MariaDB from writing to anywhere in `/home` etc. This is the standard for most Linuxes for security reasons. It is possible to work around this with bind-mounting or allowing users mess with directories outside `/home`, but neither of those strikes me as particularly great ideas.)
- Following @yotheguitou's comment, you can improve memory usage a bit by plugging the mariadb connection directly into `pd.read_sql` and using the `chunksize` parameter. Memory usage is still huge (30GB fof the generator object, 10GB more during the creation of the dataframe), but only about half what my original approach was. An additional caveat is that `pd.read_sql` throws a `UserWarning: pandas only supports SQLAlchemy connectable...` warning. This may or may not mean that there are any real problems in some cases - for the case I tried, it seemed fine. The code would be:

  `chunks = pd.read_sql(statement, connection, chunksize=50000000)
  dfx = pd.concat(list(chunks))`

**Additional Information**

MariaDB version is 11.2.2, Python version is 3.11.6, python-mariadb connector version is 1.1.8, Linux is Arch Linux with kernel 6.7.4.

Comment: Have you tried pandas.read_sql with chunksize parameter ?

Comment: @yotheguitou Thanks. chunksize improves things a bit. As `pd.read_sql(statement, connection)` (or `pd.read_sql(statement, connection, chunksize=50000000)`) does, it still requires lots more memory than the final data frame. A chunksize of, e.g. 50 million reduces this from 90GB to about 30GB, which rises to about 40GB during `df = pd.concat(list(chunks))`. This is an improvement though and it may be tweaked by using different chunksizes and perhaps with better garbage collection (since I don't see why the generator object should take up 30GB when the final data frame only takes up 8GB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some less memory intensive suggestions:

**Client/Server protocol/communication**

Use unbuffered cursor, a buffered cursor will allocate additional memory to store the retrieved data:

```
cursor= connection.cursor(buffered=False)
```

Check the average length of your both integer columns:

```
SELECT AVG(LENGTH(col1)), AVG(LENGTH(col2)) FROM my_table
```

If the average length for an BIGINT column is larger then 8 (or larger than 4 for an INT column), then use binary protocol:

```
cursor = connection.cursor(buffered=False, binary=True)
```

In Binary protocol the server doesn't send values as strings. E.g. the bigint value 17592186044416 (14 digits) will be sent as 8-byte binary.

**Don't use fetchall()**

While a normal integer value requires 4 byte in C, Python stores it in a PythonObject of type PyLong. Beside 16 bytes for reference count and base object additional memory is required to store the value for Python's bignum implementation. This means that for each Int variable at least 4 times more memory must be allocated than the actual value requires.

So instead to fetch all data at once, fetch them in portions and append the rows to the DataFrame:

```
size= 1024
while rows:=cursor.fetchmany(size)
    df.append(rows)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Two small comments: 1. `append()` is deprecated and will throw FutureWarnings, `concat()` can be used instead. 2. There's probably a tradeoff between memory usage and computation time in the choice of the chunk size. Only a thousand rows at a time will take really long. A couple of million rows at a time is much faster and still quite reasonable in terms of memory requirements. Details in the solution section added in the question above.

Comment: Of course you have to bench the right size, therefore I didn't write fetchmany(1024). size=1024 gave me better results than larger numbers when testing it with select seq,seq FROM seq_1_to_500000000 (without appending to the dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  Do more of the calculations in SQL as you fetch it.  Python is interpretive, hence one number takes much more than one number's worth of memory.

Plan B:  Prototype in Python, then transliterate to C++.  There a `DOUBLE` will take only 8 bytes (for example).